# Gson how to dynamically set serialized name

Tags: java, json, gson

Here is my case

```
// a base class
public abstract class PageResult<T> {
   @SerializedName("success")
   public boolean success = false;
   @SerializedName("next_page")
   public int nextPage = -1;
   public ArrayList<T> dataList;
}
```

in `dataList` `SerializedName` need to be dynamic i.e.

```
public class StringPageResult extends PageResult<String>{
  //for this case 
  @SerializedName("StringResult")
  public ArrayList<String> dataList
}

public class IntegerPageResult extends PageResult<Integer>{
  //for this case 
  @SerializedName("IntegerResult")
  public ArrayList<Integer> dataList
}
```

So the class extending PageResult, `SerializedName` need to be different and all must use dataList. Meaning I need to use PageResult `dataList` for various processing instead of sub class `dataList`.Is it possible?
I am doing it in following manner

```
public abstract class PageResult<T> {
  public abstract ArrayList<T> getDataList();
  @SerializedName("success")
  public boolean success = false;
  @SerializedName("next_page")
  public int nextPage = -1;
}

public class StringPageResult extends PageResult<String>{

  @SerializedName("StringResult")
  public ArrayList<String> dataList;
  public abstract ArrayList<String> getDataList(){
     return dataList;
  }
}
```

Comment: I suppose in `IntegerPageResult` the `dataList` should be of type `ArrayList<Integer>`? Apart from that, what is not working?

Comment: @david.mihola: When I use the single `dataList` on all sub classes, then it will come empty when I access `PageResult.dataList`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this :

```
@SerializedName(value="name1", alternate={"name2", "name3"})
```

https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html